# How to make route parameters optional in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-router

In Ember.js, given these routes:

```
this.route('chefs', { path: ":country/chefs"});
this.route('recipes', { path: ":country/recipes"});
```

I am required to put the positional params in the link-to component, like:

```
{{#link-to 'chefs' 'mx'}}Mexico Chefs{{/link-to}}
```

How can I avoid specifying some params in all my link-to components?

I'm thinking the 'chefs' route could use a default parameter coming from a service. But how? Any other ideas?

Here is a Twiddle:
https://ember-twiddle.com/fe34f195723fffa88869558e94f3fabc

**Edit**

Another example for this need is when using nested routes. Imagine a menu component with links to "chefs" and "recipes". When placed inside a parent route named 'country', say "/ca", the links don't need params.

```
{{#link-to 'chefs'}}Chefs{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'recipes'}}Recipes{{/link-to}}
```

These will navigate between '/ca/chefs' and '/ca/recipes'. But when this hypothetical menu is put on a root-level route, say '/login', the menu will error out "Assertion Failed: You attempted to define a `{{link-to "chefs"}}` but did not pass the parameters required for generating its dynamic segments..."

I would like to give the route a default "country" parameter when one is not passed by the link.

One alternative I see, which doesn't seem too elegant, is to create a service and inject the "country" param in every link.

Comment: Think in terms of URLs.  What would that open-ended chefs URL look like?

Comment: {{#link-to 'chefs'}}Chefs{{/link-to}} would go to /ca/chefs for Canadian visitors and to /mx/chefs for visitors from Mexico